# Trigger github action on push to multiple branches

Tags: github, github-actions

According to [document](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags), we can specify multiple branches on push event. According to my understanding, if we us a workflow description file like below,

```
...

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev

...
```

when I push to `master` branch or `dev` branch, this workflow should run. But in reality, when I locate this workflow file at `master` branch, only pushes to `master` branch triggers workflow run. Additionally, when I locate this file on `dev` branch, only pushes to `dev` branch triggers workflow run.

It seems that though I specify multiple branches to workflow file, workflow runs only when target branch and location of workflow file matches. If this is true, I'm not sure why `branches` key exists. It pretends to work on multiple branches.

Can anybody explain details on this?

Comment: I can't find the definitive docs for it, but I remember that your yaml file should be stored in the main branch for your triggers, but each branch should have a copy of the workflow. You can have a different workflow in each branch, but the triggers will be read from the main branch.

It can indeed be confusing.

Comment: https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/github_actions_1_cicd_triggers.html

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for your answer. I found that `main` is not the one and only branch which triggers workflow. Basically, each push/PR works on workflow files on it's own branch. @jidicula's link should help. Thanks!

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for sharing link. It does not help me directly but it was good. The exact answer for my question is jidicula's link. THanks!